# String matching and ranking logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if anyone here could come up with some solution for me that would take 2 strings and compare then word by word to give me a percentage match of the entire string.

Example: If I wanted to compare these 2 strings

1. The Elf on the Shelf: A Christmas Musical (Touring)
2. The Elf on the Shelf Musical Baltimore

In SQL if I do a `like` comparison it won't match.
But if I can break up each word and say if it matches we would see that 6 of the 7 words match from string 2 to string 1. And then could say 85% match

Thanks!

Comment: Suppose string 2 was just `the` then you would have a 100% match. You may need to refine your metric.

Comment: @PeterSmith i would prob build out a bunch of basic words to exclude like "and" "the" etc

Comment: Yes, but `elf` would also give you 100%

Comment: @petersmith yes I would prob have to make it that there are at least a certain amount of words. Maybe at least 4 words

Comment: If you can split the two strings into two temp tables of words then you could use something like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738548/help-comparing-two-lists-with-sql) but there is no out of the box solution without doing some work on your input

Comment: @petersmith yes I think that would be the ideal solution. I just don’t know how to split the strings into temp tables of words.

Comment: Take a look at the Levenshtein distance algorithm - there are plenty of examples available and even a thread on SO.  Here is one: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-edit-distance-and-the-levenshtein-algorithm/

Comment: "I just don’t know how to split the strings into temp tables of words" - there are loads of questions on this site explaining this.

Comment: Are you concerned with ordinal position or just matching words - ie "The elf on shelf" and "The elf shelf on" are 50% or 100%?

Comment: @stu I don’t care about position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution for getting the percentage of matching words, this assumes the words match between the two strings irrespective of position.

I appreciate it may not be exactly what you are after and doesn't do "similar" words, but hopefully meets the criteria for a percentage match. There's plenty of scope to tweak if it's not exactly what's needed.

Here the two strings are broken up into rows and merged into a single table, after stripping out common punctuation. Then a *row_number window function* partitions them by matching words and counts each pair. Finally this is counted for just the matching pairs and summed with a count of the repeating words common in both, then as a percental of the shorter string.

```
declare 
    @s1 varchar(100)='The Elf on the Shelf: A Christmas Musical. (Touring)',
    @s2 varchar(100)='The Elf on the Shelf Musical, Baltimore';

with words as (
    select 1 s, Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(value,':',''),',',''),'(',''),')',''),'.','') word
    from String_Split(@s1,' ')
    union all
    select 2, Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(value,':',''),',',''),'(',''),')',''),'.','') 
from String_Split(@s2,' ')
), matching as (
  select *, Row_Number() over(partition by word order by s) rn
  from words
), final as (
  select * , Count(*) over(partition by word, s) repeating, Count(*) over() * 1.0 totwords, sum(Iif(s=1,1,0)) over() s1words
  from matching
  outer apply(values(Iif(rn=2 and rn=s,1,0)))x(p)
)
select (Sum (p) + max(case when s=1 and repeating>1 then repeating end))
        / Max(Iif(totwords/s1words>0.5, totwords-s1words, s1words)) * 100 [Matching Words %]
from final
```

Here, 6 words in each string match, so it results in the desired 6 being 85.7% of the shorter 7-word string.

[Example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=77d143fe32d92f5fc675c244f81bb4d4)

Comment: this looks promising! im having an issue running this. im getting these errors: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6
'Translate' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 9
'Translate' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: @kivi12k *Translate* appeared in SQL Server 2017, you must be on an older version of SQL Server 2016/2014/2012? It's a handy way of removing multiple characters at the same time, otherwise you end up with a bunch of nested replace() which you might have to do, eg `replace(replace(@string,':',''),',','')` etc for the puntuation to strip out.

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 r2

Comment: yup. any chance you could re-write it with nested replace? thanks!

Comment: i also noticed besides the replace issue its giving issues with the = and >. any ideas?
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: Iif not recognized function it says.

Comment: 13-year-old 2008R2 is really a bit of cruicial information, there is no *string_split'; it will require a custom replacement function instead - easily doable though I will revisit when I have time.

Comment: I guess I could upgrade to a later version of sql. Not sure why I’m still using 2008 either ‍♂️

Comment: That would of course be preferable, then you could take advantage of this answer and so many other improvements in the product.

Comment: im being told from my admin that we cannot upgrade to a newer version yet and it might be a couple months. Any chance you would be able to re-code the solution you wrote for 2008 version of sql ? sorry to bother you!

Comment: there seems to be some issue that i just noticed. its giving matches even when it shouldnt be the case. take example this:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=93a5d1edd710b3fac51e4e422490f7fd

its saying 66.66% match when really i should be 0. Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the similarity between two strings. There are many algorithms you can accomplish this with. Let's try out the [Levenshtein](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-edit-distance-and-the-levenshtein-algorithm/) distance and the [Longest Common Subsequence](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-the-longest-common-subsequence/); each with their own advantages.

```
-- Sample strings
DECLARE 
 @string1 VARCHAR(100) = 'The Elf on the Shelf: A Christmas Musical (Touring)',
 @string2 VARCHAR(100) = 'The Elf on the Shelf Musical Baltimore';

--uncomment to test:
--SELECT @string1 = 'Their', @string2 = 'Theirs'

-- Longest Common Subsequence Solution
SELECT Similarity = 1.*LEN(dbo.LongestCommonSubsequence(@string1,@string2))/L2
FROM
(
  SELECT MIN(f.S), MAX(f.S)
  FROM  (VALUES(LEN(@string1)),(LEN(@string2))) AS f(S)
) f(L1,L2);

-- Levenshtein
SELECT Similarity = (1.*L1-Lev)/L2
FROM
(
  SELECT MIN(f.S), MAX(f.S), dbo.LEVENSHTEIN(@string1,@string2)
  FROM  (VALUES(LEN(@string1)),(LEN(@string2))) AS f(S)
) f(L1,L2,Lev);
```

Each return:

```
Similarity
---------------------------------------
0.62745098039


Similarity
---------------------------------------
0.31372549019
```

For "their" and "theirs" you get:

```
Similarity
---------------------------------------
0.83333333333

Similarity
---------------------------------------
0.66666666666
```